# Spring Boot Camel Testing - No consumers available on endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am testing spring security in my Spring Boot, Camel application.  When I attempt to test a route using an Autowired ProducerTemplate, an exception is thrown with a message "No consumers available on endpoint: direct://secure".  The route is properly defined within the camel context.

RouteBuilder code:

```
@Component
public class SpringSecurityRoute extends RouteBuilder {
    protected Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringSecurityRoute.class);

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        from("direct:secure")
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    logger.info("********************* Processing!");
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Test class code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringSecurityRouteTest {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringSecurityRouteTest.class);

    @Autowired
    ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testRoute() {
        logger.info("Starting test.");
        producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:secure", "body");
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[ID-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-51669-1484755486463-0-2]

    at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1706)
    at org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.extractResultBody(ExchangeHelper.java:677)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:515)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.extractResultBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:511)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:163)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:168)
    at com.incomm.imp.neo.routes.SpringSecurityRouteTest.testRoute(SpringSecurityRouteTest.java:37)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: direct://secure. Exchange[ID-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-51669-1484755486463-0-2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectProducer.process(DirectProducer.java:55)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:197)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:529)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache$1.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:497)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInProducer(ProducerCache.java:365)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.sendExchange(ProducerCache.java:497)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.send(ProducerCache.java:225)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.send(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:144)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultProducerTemplate.sendBody(DefaultProducerTemplate.java:161)
    ... 35 more
```

Comment: You may want to take note that this is not a unit test because it relies on integrating several components, so you might want to alter your approach and make it an integration test.  Changing your perspective accordingly might help with these initialization issues.

Comment: I just offered the above as a comment because it does not *directly* help you to fix this issue.  And it is an old issue, so I am stating my advice for posterity.

Answer (score 2):

I had to spend a lot of time working through this issue also. It turned out that my `RouteBuilder` was not getting added to the `CamelContext` because I did not have a `@Component` annotation on the `RouteBuilder` class.

I see that you have included the necessary `@Component` annotation on your `RouteBuilder` (`SpringSecurityRoute`), but what I can't tell from your post is whether or not your `SpringSecurityRoute` is being added to the Spring context with a component scan or some other such means. One way to tell for sure would be to see if the route has been added to your context before you call #sendBody on your `ProducerTemplate` like so:

```
@Test
public void testRoute() {

  logger.info("Starting test.");

  List<Route> routes = producerTemplate.getCamelContext().getRoutes();
  // inspect list of routes in your debugger and see if your route is
  // present within the camel context.

  producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:secure", "body");
}
```

If it is *not* there, it *will* cause the "No consumers available on endpoint" error mentioned in the title of your post. So make sure you're doing a component scan on the package that contains your route.

Here's how I wire mine together:

Route builder:

```
package com.example.camel.routes;

import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class HelloCamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {

  public void configure() {
    from("direct:sayHello").to("stream:out");
  }
}
```

Spring Java config:

```
package com.example.camel.routes;

import org.apache.camel.spring.javaconfig.CamelConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example.camel.routes")
public class CamelConfig extends CamelConfiguration {
}
```

And I include it in my unit test class like so:

```
package com.example.camel.routes;
    
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Produce;
import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.Route;
import org.apache.camel.test.spring.CamelSpringRunner;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
    
import java.util.List;

@RunWith(CamelSpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = CamelConfig.class)
public class HelloCamelRouteIT {
    
  @Autowired
  protected CamelContext camelContext;
    
  @Produce
  protected ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;
    
  @Test
  public void doit() {
    producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:sayHello", "Hello!");
  }
}
```

### Console output:

Hello!

Comment: I upvoted your answer because it's a decent approach.  But these are integration tests, so the only problem I have with them is that they are not specified as integration tests (e.g., with an "IT" postfix to the test class name, etc) so the perspective might not be ideal for dealing with the complexity of the initialization with Spring and Camel, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the upvote and feedback @SteveStorck. That was just a detail I missed. I updated it with an edit in the post.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that camel context is not initialized before the test is run.  If a delay is added for the camel context to become ready before running the test, the error goes away.  I added the following code to the test classes to give camel context 5 seconds to initialize.  The exception is no longer thrown.  I noticed that without the added delay, no log statements are printed that suggest that route is ready.

```
11:23:11.440 [CamelMainRunController] INFO  o.a.camel.spring.SpringCamelContext - Route: route3 started and consuming from: direct://secure
```

New code added to test class:

```
private boolean isCamelContextInitialized = false;

@Before
public void initializeCamelContext() throws Exception {
    if (!isCamelContextInitialized) {
        logger.info("Waiting for Camel Context to become initialized.");
        Thread.sleep(5000L);
    }
}
```

Updated test class code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringSecurityRouteTest {

    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringSecurityRouteTest.class);
    private boolean isCamelContextInitialized = false;

    @Before
    public void initializeCamelContext() throws Exception {
        if (!isCamelContextInitialized) {
            logger.info("Waiting for Camel Context to become initialized.");
            Thread.sleep(5000L);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Test
    public void testRoute() {
        logger.info("Starting test.");
        producerTemplate.sendBody("direct:secure", "body");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are other runners to use when you are testing camel in a spring boot application.  Have a look at https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/spring-testing.html to get you pointed in the right direction.